# Keeping a column in sync with another column in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a column always *kept in sync* with another column in the same table.

Let this table be an example:

```
+------+-----------+
| name | name_copy |
+------+-----------+
| John | John      |
+------+-----------+
| Mary | Mary      |
+------+-----------+
```

I'd like to:

Be able to `INSERT` into this table, using providing a value only for the `name` column - The `name_copy` column should automatically take the value I used in `name`

When `UPDATE`-ing the `name` column on a pre-existing row, the `name_copy` should automatically update to match the new & updated `name_column`.

#### Some solutions

- I could do this via code but that would be terribly bad as there's no guarantee the data would always be accessible by my code (what if someone changes the data through a DB client?)

What would be a safe and reliable and easy way to tackle this in Postgres?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/triggers.html). Simple trigger function:

```sql
create or replace function trigger_on_example()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    new.name_copy := new.name;
    return new;
end
$$;
```

In **Postgres 12+** there is a nice alternative in the form of [generated columns.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html)

```sql
create table my_table(
    id int, 
    name text, 
    name_copy text generated always as (name) stored);
```

Note that a generated column cannot be written to directly.

Test both solutions in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/lFI7u3m0)

Answer (score 2):

Don't put `name_copy` into the table.  One method is to create the column and access it using a view:

```
create view v_table as
     select t.*, name as name_copy
     from t;
```

That said, I don't really see a use for this.

Comment: Thanks - I won't - It's just some sample I've put there to get the point - Isn't there a way to do this without using views - E.g Something like a MySQL Trigger-like behavior?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides . . . Of course you can use a trigger, but that is a lot of effort to maintain this.